# Where to find Microsoft Build engine Redistributables

Tags: .net, msbuild, c#-3.0

I want to use build engine api in one of my project. I know that these are pre-installed with visual studio. I want to know that does it really required visual studio full installation to use these api or can I get the re-distributable for it? I am seeking a way whether can I avoid visual studio installation?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is included in .NET, so you just need to redistribute the appropriate version of .NET (full profile - client profile does not include MSBuild).